# URL Routing doesn't work with file extension without slash

Tags: .net, routes

I'm trying to dynamically create an XML file using .NET and URLRouting...

In my global.asax:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("FederationMetadataRoute", "FederationMetadata/2007-06/{file}", "~/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.aspx")
```

Using the above route in my global.asax, the following URL scenarios are displayed below:

**Works:**
https://MyDomain.com/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml/
https://MyDomain.com/FederationMetadata/2007-06/AnythingWithoutExtension

**Doesn't work:**
https://MyDomain.com/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml
https://MyDomain.com/FederationMetadata/2007-06/AnythingWith.Extension

**This is the URL that MUST work but does not:**
https://MyDomain.com/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  Apparently I had to have runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
        ...
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```